# How to using extending the same masterpage layout in two partials?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have two page on Laravel.

I can easily extend this layout in another blade partial to get a working modal with a header, content, and footer which I can embed using `@extends('master')`.

My problem is:

The first page is using `header1.blade.php`.

And second page is using `header2.blade.php`.

On `master.blade.php` is my master page.

```
<body>
   @include('partials.header1')
   @yield('content') 
   @include('partials.footer')
</body>
```

On `index.blade.php` is using `master.blade.php` is master page with `extends('master.blade.php`).

On `listnews.blade.php` have same master page.

I want at `listnews.blade.php` using `partials.header2`.

Have any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to @lewis4u's answer you can use the `@section` directve.

This way you can define the default header to be used but you can change it whenever you need to.

Firstly, change your `master.blade.php` file to be:

```
<body>
@section('header')
    @include('partials.header1')
@show
@yield('content')
@include('partials.footer')
</body>
```

Then in your `listnews.blade.php` file just add another section after the extends:

```
@section('header')
    @include('partials.header2')
@endsection
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: does this simply overwrite the section('header')?

Comment: I will delete my answer because i find your more elegant!